# Adicionar milésimos no contador jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contador

Estou com um código Javascript que faz um contador de **Dias / Horas / Minutos / Segundos** . Só que preciso que ele também conte os milésimos, só que tenho pouco conhecimento em javascript e não sei como incrementar essa opção. O código que faz a contagem acima é o seguinte:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options) {
        var settings = { 'date': null };
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        this_sel = $(this);

        function count_exec() {
            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000; // Parse the date string
            currentDate =   Math.floor($.now() / 1000); // Find the timestamp for now
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate; // Find the number of seconds remaining
            if (seconds <= 0) { // After the event date has passed
                days = 0;
                hours = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                milese = 0;

            } else {
                days =          Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));       // Divide to find the number of days remaining
                seconds -=      days * 60 * 60 * 24;                        // Subtract the number of (complete, => 24 hours) days calculated above

                hours =         Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));            // Get the number of hours from that modified number ^
                seconds -=      hours * 60 * 60;

                minutes =       Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                seconds -=      minutes * 60;



            }
            this_sel.find('#days').val(days).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#hours').val(hours).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#mins').val(minutes).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#secs').val(seconds).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#mile').val(milese).trigger('change');

        } // End of count_exec();

        count_exec();

        interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);

    } // End of the main function
}) (jQuery);
```

A variavel **milese** e **#mile** fui eu que criei para colocar os milésimos, mas não dei continuidade pois não entendi a lógica do código original.

Comment: Edite a resposta e coloque o código original sem a sua alteração e coloque a parte em HTML necessária para ele funcionar, se possível já funcionando em um jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

A lógica desse plugin não é das mais claras, mas se você olhar bem, ele mantém a data desejada (`eventDate`) e a data atual (`currentDate`) em segundos ao dividir os valores originais por `1000`.

Para adicionar milisegundos, basta parar de dividir por `1000` e mudar o código existente para fazer os cálculos baseados em milisegundos. Basicamente é só multiplicar por `1000` em vários lugares e incluir sua nova variável `millis` nessas contas.

Também é preciso mudar o timer (em `setInterval()`) para executar mais rápido. Eu Só não recomendo executar a cada `1` milisegundo porque é muito mais rápido do que o browser consegue processar e que nós conseguimos distinguir. Para o browser o intervalo mínimo fica entre 4ms e 10ms. Eu usei 50ms abaixo.

Aqui está o código que eu mudei:

(function($) {
        $.fn.countdown = function(options) {
            var settings = { 'date': null };
            if(options) {
                $.extend(settings, options);
            }

```
        this_sel = $(this);

        function count_exec() {
            var eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']); // Parse the date string
            var currentDate = $.now(); // Find the timestamp for now
            var millis = eventDate - currentDate; // Find the number of seconds remaining
            if (seconds <= 0) { // After the event date has passed
                days = 0;
                hours = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                millis = 0;

            } else {
                // Divide to find the number of days remaining
                days =          Math.floor(millis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));       
                // Subtract the number of (complete, => 24 hours) days calculated above
                millis -=       days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;                        

                // Get the number of hours from that modified number
                hours =         Math.floor(millis / (1000 * 60 * 60));            
                millis -=       hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;

                minutes =       Math.floor(millis / 1000 * 60);
                millis -=       minutes * 1000 * 60;

                seconds =       Math.floor(millis / 1000);
                millis -=       minutes * 1000;
            }
            this_sel.find('#days').val(days).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#hours').val(hours).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#mins').val(minutes).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#secs').val(seconds).trigger('change');
            this_sel.find('#mile').val(millis).trigger('change');

        } // End of count_exec();

        count_exec();

        interval = setInterval(count_exec, 50);

    } // End of the main function
}) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

[<sub>**fonte**</sub>](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp)

Retorna os milissegundos, de acordo com o horário local
`var millisecond = new Date().getMilliseconds();`

```
hours        = new Date().getHours()
minutes      = new Date().getMinutes()
seconds      = new Date().getSeconds()
milliseconds = new Date().getMilliseconds()

document.write( hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds )
```

<sup>**output do exemplo acima**</sup>
<sup>4:59:55:618</sup>

<sup>**exemplo no jsfiddle**</sup>
<sup>**http://jsfiddle.net/hq8nx7yb/**</sup>
Basta você ajustar aos seus parâmetros

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar a encaixar no código que postei? Aquele código é o countdown.js que realiza a contagem.